# How can I get my application database offline?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I've got an internal ASP.Net application which I would like to send to someone. The problem I have is that the app is using local SQL Server database. Is it possible to have a copy of the database to the file and just replace the access to the db for the file? If yes how?

Comment: Cant you just do a backup/restore?

Comment: I just want to show someone the front end of the application, the backend is not important, so looking for the simple solution, and not sure if they have SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would sign up for a free Microsoft Azure account, use the free [Azure Migration tool](https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) to copy your database to Azure, then just change your `web.config` to point at the Azure database.

This saves having to buy any *SQL Server* licenses, and requires the fewest amount of changes to your app.

Comment: Perfect, I actually have an Azure account

Answer (score 0):

No, they'll need SQL Server as well. They can install a free Express edition if they're eligible for the license.

If you set up your application properly, it should be easy to replace the data layer with a portable database like SQLite, so they don't have to install anything.